# Grob arguments from a data.frame to ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, arguments, grob

How can I pass the arguments of a set of grobs (ximin, xmax, ymin, ymax) from a data.frame to the annotation_custom function (ggplot2). The following example illustrates the problem.

```
# Grobs
a <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_histogram(fill = "red") + theme_void()
g1 <- ggplotGrob(a)
b <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) + geom_histogram(fill = "blue") + theme_void()
g2 <- ggplotGrob(b)

# Structure of the arguments location
my.data <- data.frame(grob = c("g1", "g2"), xmin = c(1.5, 5.5), xmax = c(4.5, 8), 
                  ymin = c(2.5, 4), ymax = c(6, 8))

# Desired result
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_blank() + theme_bw() +
annotation_custom(g1, xmin = 1.5, xmax = 4.5, ymin = 2.5, ymax = 6) +
annotation_custom(g2, xmin = 5.5, xmax = 8, ymin = 4, ymax = 8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be more natural with a `geom_custom()` but in the meantime you can create a list of layers,

```
my.data <- data.frame(xmin = c(1.5, 5.5), xmax = c(4.5, 8), 
                      ymin = c(2.5, 4), ymax = c(6, 8))
my.data$grob <- list(g1,g2)
get_grob <- function(grob, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax){
  annotation_custom(grob=grob[[1]], xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)
}
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_blank() + theme_bw() +
  plyr::mlply(my.data, get_grob)
```